# Error 2738 could not access VBScript run time for custom action

Tags: windows-installer, vbscript

If you recently removed McAfee antivirus from your laptop machine and after that you started to face this error message "Error 2738 could not access VBScript run time for custom action" each time you try to use .msi installer.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone find this annoying error message when running a .msi installer. I have lenovo laptop that was equipped with Macafee Antivirus then I removed it after that the error started to appear!!! you can follow these steps to solve this problem:

Go to Mcafee and download McAfee Consumer Product Removal tool (MCPR) from here: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/mcafee_consumer_product_removal_tool.html

After that download Microsoft fix 50842 from here : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9804433
You will be surprised that everything is going ok now.

:) good luck